# Not able to add an app part to the page with a shared provider hosted app

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, app-part, catalog

**Situation:**
I created a SharePoint provider hosted app that contains an app part.
I installed the app inside the app catalog.
By using the deployment option on an app installed in the app catalog, I pushed the app to several sites.

**Problem:**
In the app catalog site I can add the app part. But any other site, where I pushed to app to, the app part is not visible in the "*Ribbon > Insert > App part*". 
Unless, I add that app to that site (by add an app).

**Question:**
How can I add an app part to a page when using a shared provider hosted app?

Comment: You have to add the app to the site before you can add an app part from the app.  Adding the app to the app catalog will not do this.

Comment: I added the app to the catalog, and also activated it in the app catalog. And from there I deployed the app to other site collections, but in the site collections I deployed to the app part is not visible.
If I activate it directly in the site, the app part is available. But, I want to use the technique of using it as a tenant app and activate it in the app catalog and "push" it to other site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (at this point) using app parts for tenant-scoped ("shared") add-ins is still not possible. See the section "Limitations" on this page: [Tenancies and deployment scopes for SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179896.aspx):

> **Limitations of tenant-scoped add-ins**
>
> The following kinds of add-ins cannot be batch-installed:
>
> - Add-ins that contain a custom action for the ribbon. (Custom actions that are deployed as menu items are allowed.)
> - **Add-ins that contain an add-in part.**

It also seems unlikely this will change. See the feedback from Microsoft on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/5622390-global-web-part-catalog-enabling-app-parts-for-ten):

> This is an interesting idea. As this requires significant changes to the app infrastructure, we would want to investigate more into the scenarios and usage to determine if this is a worthy investment.